# Reading an XML file on the client using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, parsing, file-upload

I am very new to JavaScript and am attempting to read an xml file which will be uploaded by the user but running into difficulties in referencing the file.

Eventually I will want to parse the XML contents, update it and then make available for download again.

My HTML file:

```
  <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
         <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload for Reading</button>
  </div>
```

controller.js

```
  myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){    
    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));


    parser=new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(file,"text/xml");
    var length=xmlDoc.length;
    console.log(length);
```

Result:
 file is {"name":"books.xml","lastModifiedDate":"2014-08-26T16:20:03.685Z","size":818,"type":"text/xml"}

length xmlDoc.length:undefined

However the above shows xmlDoc.length is undefined.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with xml data in angular, you can use the XML to Javascript mapping library ([x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/)). For use you can follow below steps:

1. Install the X2JS library from link above
2. Create a custom factory to convert `xml` to `json` and vice-versa

   ```
   angular.factory('xmlParser', function() { 
     var x2js = new X2JS();
      return {
        xml2json: x2js.xml2json,
        json2xml: x2js.json2xml_str
      }
   });
   ```
3. Create a `transformeRequest interceptor` in your `$http` request to convert your file data to json before sending

   ```
    angular.factory('Data', [$http, 'xmlParser',
       function($http, xmlParser) {
          $http.post('/api/msgs.xml', data, {
          transformRequest: function(data) {
             return xmlParser.xml2json(data);
          }
       })
     });
   ```